# Calling heightForRowAtIndexPath manually

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, tableview

In my tableview, the table is loaded, than the images get loaded and when the images are loaded I want to call this function again from the ProductTableViewCell.swift file where I configure the cell.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:  NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
 return cell.frame.size.height
}
```

how can I do that?

EDIT:

```
import UIKit

class ProductTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

//var appleview: AppleProductsTableViewController!
@IBOutlet weak var productImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var productTitleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var productDescriptionLabel: UILabel!
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds



func configureCellWith(product: Product){
    productImageView.image = product.image
    productDescriptionLabel.text = product.description
    productTitleLabel.text = product.title

    var urlstring = product.imageURL

    ImageLoader.sharedLoader.imageForUrl(urlstring as String, completionHandler:{(image: UIImage?, url: String) in
 //self.productImageView.frame.size = orgframe.frame.size
        self.productImageView.image = image!

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.productImageView.frame.size = (image?.size)!

            while self.productImageView.frame.size.height > 0.4 * self.screenSize.height {
                self.productImageView.frame.size.width = self.productImageView.frame.size.width * 0.9
                self.productImageView.frame.size.height = self.productImageView.frame.size.height * 0.9
                println("kleiner 2")
            }
            while self.productImageView.frame.size.width > 0.6 * self.screenSize.width{
                self.productImageView.frame.size.width = self.productImageView.frame.size.width * 0.9
                self.productImageView.frame.size.height = self.productImageView.frame.size.height * 0.9
                println("kleinrer")
            }
            self.productTitleLabel.center.y = self.productImageView.center.y + self.productImageView.frame.size.height/2 + 15
            self.productDescriptionLabel.center.y = self.productTitleLabel.center.y + 28

            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("renew", object: nil)
        })


    })


}


}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

So the

```
heightForRowAtIndexPath
```

will be called again, and all your cells get the "new" calculated height. Better idea (in most cases) is to use Autolayout to automatically calculate the needed space.

Edit: If you want to reload your table from any class, you could use a Notification.

So in your TableView:

```
 func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "reloadTable:",name:"renew", object: nil)
}

    func reloadTable(notification: NSNotification){
    //load data here
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

And this in your cell.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("renew", object: nil)
```

Comment: but I have 2 classes, 1 for the tableview and 1 for the tableviewcell. I need to call it from the tableviewcell class but I can't. because the tableviewcell doesn't have a member named tableview, and If I use TableViewController.tableView.reloadData() I get an lldb error. I know i am being dumb and it is simple to solve, but can't figure out how

Comment: You could use a NSNotification for updating your table from any class (where you add your Notifications) - i will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks it works, but it gets stuck in a loop, is there a way to update the rowheight without the override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {} function beging called?

Comment: No, that is always called together (but why do you not return the same cells?)

Comment: I do return the same cells, but it gets stuck in a loop. Take a look at my productTableViewcell(see edit)

Comment: Oh, thats not a good idea here. Can you tell us a little bit what your project look like? There is a table with Images which are loaded async, or? And the images are not always the same size?

Comment: Ok i would to the following: Create a Cell with Autolayout and an empty ImageView, after all Images (or only 1) are loaded reload your TableView.  I think thats the most elegant way to solve that.

Comment: Hmm sounds very logical, but how can I do that?

Comment: Here is all you need: http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81221/discussion-between-sdd-and-derdida).

Answer (score 2):

There is a "sneaky" way to do this.

If you use:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

None of the cells will be reloaded but heightForRowAt will be triggered and the cell will resize themself.

Credits to Hamish Rickerby ([blog](https://hamishrickerby.com/2012/07/06/updating-a-uitableview-without-calling-reloaddata/))